# div inside a div; is there a way to force the inner div to be at the bottom of the outer div?

Tags: html, css

Hi I am looking to place the 'learn more' button at the bottom of the page. It's a div.learn-more inside a div.container. Is there a way to force the div.learn-more to the bottom of div.container, in a similar fashion that floating a div right/left will force it to the right or left side of the page? Thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/vaKsk/

html

```
<div class="container">    

<div class="page1">
    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Support</li>
            <li>Sign Up</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="page1-content centered">
        <h1> Generic Header</h1>
        <h2> Generic Content 1</h2>
        <h2> Generic Content 2</h2>
        <h2> Generic Content 3</h2>    
</div>    

<div class="learn-more centered">
    <a href="#learn" id="click"> learn more </a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="page2-content" id="text">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}

.centered {
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center; 
}
nav {
  list-style: none;

}

.navigation ul li { 
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    margin: 5px;
}

.page1-content {
    clear:both;
}

.learn-more a {
    color:red;
}

.page2-content {
    margin: 200px 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    background-size: 100% 1000px;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaKsk/2/)

```
.container{position:relative; height:400px;}
.learn-more{position:absolute; bottom:0;text-align:center;}
```

Comment: thank you this is just what I was looking for. However my .centered class is not not working properly, how would I use the absolute positioning of the .learn-more div while also keeping it centered with the rest of the elements on the page?

Comment: nevermind, it looks like adding left:0 and right:0 does the trick

Comment: Yes, You can do this...:)

Answer (score 1):

Make the div.container positioned relative and the div.learn-mor positioned absolute with bottom of 0px.
CSS:

```
div.container
{
  position:relative;
}

div.learn-more
{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```